# Is it $\sigma$-ring?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Is it true that if a (not empty) class of sets is closed under the symmetric differences ($A\Delta B:=(A-B)\cup(B-A)$) and countable intersections, then it is a $\sigma$-ring? I proved that ring. I have problem with the countable infinite union. 
**Proof.** $E\cup F=(E\Delta F)\Delta(E\cap F)$, and $E-F=E\Delta(E\cap F)$. So a ring. $\blacksquare$ 
I don't know how to generalize the first identity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\mathscr{F}$ be the family of finite subsets of $\Bbb N$. $\mathscr{F}$ is clearly closed under symmetric difference but not under countable union, since $\Bbb N=\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb N}\{n\}\notin\mathscr{F}$.

Comment: Very simple counter-example.